# How to get property of dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, onclick

I have some trouble with my project,

I need to build a game : Mine Sweeper,

My main problem in this project is that I have dynamic table in my html page 
that I build that matrix in my Javascript page,

I want to get the current cell I pushed it by onclick event and I only got the first cell (0,0):

It's my home work project , I only need help to understand how can I get the index of each cell I`ve been clicked on ,

my html page :

```
<body onload="initGame()">
    <header>
      <h1>My Mine Sweeper</h1>
    </header>

    <table class="mineTable" onclick="cellClicked(this)" border="1">
          <tbody class="mineSweeperTable" ></tbody>
    </table>
```

my javascript Page :

```
    'use strict';

var gMINE = '&#10057;';
var gCELL = ' ';
var gLevel = {
      SIZE : 4 ,
      MINES: 0.2
};
var gCell ={
    i : 0 ,
    j : 1
}

var gMineSweeper = [];

function getRandomCell() {

    return (Math.random() > gLevel.MINES)? gCELL : gMINE ;  
}

function initGame() {

  buildBoard();
  renderBoard(gMineSweeper);
  countMines(gMineSweeper);
  //setMinesNeighborsCount(gMineSweeper);
}

function buildBoard() {
  var elCell = document.querySelectorAll ('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < gLevel.SIZE; i++) {
    gMineSweeper.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < gLevel.SIZE; j++) {
      gMineSweeper[i][j] = getRandomCell();
    }
  }
}

function renderBoard(board) {

  var elMineSweeperTable = document.querySelector('.mineSweeperTable');

  var strHTML = '';
  board.forEach(function (row) {
    strHTML += '<tr>';
    row.forEach(function (cell) {

      strHTML += '<td> ' + cell +  ' </td>'
    });    
    strHTML += '</tr>'
  })
  elMineSweeperTable.innerHTML = strHTML;
}

function countMines(board) {
  var count = 0;
  board.forEach(function(row) {
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      if(cell === gMINE){
        count++;
      }   
    });
  });
  console.log('Mines Count : ' , count);
  return count;
}

function cellClicked(elCell,i,j) {
  var elCell = document.querySelectorAll ('td');
  console.log('You Clicked on me ! : ' , elCell,i,j);
  debugger;

}
function setMinesNeighborsCount(board) {
  var elCell = document.querySelector('td');
  // debugger;
  // for (var i = 0; i < board; i++) {
  //   gMineSweeper.push([]);
  //   for (var j = 0; j < board; j++) {
  //     var ngbrsCount = countNgbrs(i, j);
  //     console.log('Cell ', i, ', ', j, ' has: ', ngbrsCount  );
  //     if (ngbrsCount > 0) {
  //       debugger;
  //       board.push(ngbrsCount);
  //       // elCell.innerHTML = ngbrsCount;
  //       cell[i][j] = ngbrsCount;
  //       elCell = cell[i][j];

  //     }
  //     // debugger;
  //     if (cell === gMINE) {
  //       console.log('This cell is Mine', i, j);
  //       // debugger;
  //       // board.push(ngbrsCount);
  //     }    
  //   }
  // }
  var c = elCell;
  debugger;
  board.forEach(function (row, i) {
    row.forEach(function (cell, j) {

      var ngbrsCount = countNgbrs(i, j);
      console.log('Cell ', i, ', ', j, ' has: ', ngbrsCount  );
      if (ngbrsCount > 0) {
        //board.push(ngbrsCount);
        // elCell.innerHTML = ngbrsCount;
        //debugger;
        c[i][j] = ngbrsCount;

      }
      debugger;
      if (cell === gMINE) {
        console.log('This cell is Mine', i, j);
        //debugger;
        // board.push(ngbrsCount);
      }    
  });
});
}
function countNgbrs(i, j) {
  var count = 0;

  for (var a = i-1; a <= i+1; a++){

    if ( a < 0 || a >= gMineSweeper.length ) continue;

    for (var b = j-1; b <= j+1; b++){

      if ( b < 0 || b >= gMineSweeper.length ) continue;
      if ( a === i && b === j ) continue;

      if (gMineSweeper[a][b] === gMINE) count++;
    }

  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the postion of the  from table tag using jQuery

HTML

```
<td onclick='Getposition($(this))'></td>

function Getposition(e){  
  var col   = e.index() + 1;
  var row   = e.closest('tr').index() + 1;
  alert( [col,row].join(',') );  
}
```

Example Fiddle
http://jsbin.com/lupifilike/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: can you please explain to me , if i need that event in my table in the html (onclick) or if there is other way to resolve it but just with simple JS/ pure JS

Comment: Then Give onclick in all td and call the function

Comment: but i have a dynamic table , i dont have <td>...

if the teacher wont said me its needs to be a dynamic table , i would gave <td> for each and will put event on each ... and didnt needed that help  :(

Comment: i appreciate it a lot buddy ,but its not the exactly answer i looking for :(

i dont have <td> in my table its a dynamic table .

Comment: Then What you want how you creating table dynamically by javascript or jquery Explain me clearly

Comment: i creating my table in my js page , by 2 functions :
 1.buildBoard() 2.renderBoard(board)

Comment: and by clicking some cell in my table i would like to know each cell i`ve been clicke even by a simple console.log(); for start

Comment: @Arthurm, I Understand that you are appending <tr> <td> tags from renderBoard function

Comment: The Problem is first you are calling initGame() method on that method is calling buildBoard there you used gLevel but you are declared any where and your gMineSweeper array is empty how your foreach will work

Comment: i do have this var  , sorry i forgot to put it here in the example , i will update it

Comment: Can u update all things in any fiddle and give me a link

Comment: i updated it , i do have some other problem , i dont understand how can i get each cell by the event of 'onclick'

Comment: please let me know i something aint clear in my project , and if you could resolve my problem

Comment: @Aruthur ok i got your fiddle i working on it if any improvement in reply you

Comment: Why you are not using JQuery

Comment: i dont work with JQuery because my i didnt study it for now , and the teacher wants me to do it simple JS , but I think i done it !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function cellClicked(el) {
  document.querySelector('.mineTable').onclick = function(){
    var el = event.target;
    console.log('td clicked' , el);
    debugger;
    if(el.innerText === gMINE){
      console.log('Game Over!  ');

    }
  };
}
```

its working that way :)